# Processing js server side

Tags: javascript, server-side

I need to know how is the best way to solve the problem below:

I have an online editor, where the user write a js code to solve some problem, like a challenge. So, I need to get this code, and proccess it in a server, to check if the code was written correctly, comparing the results.

Do I need to call a js shell in server side or something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Running any code written by the user on your server would be a great security issue.

Instead, run the code on the client with [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval). Then send the **result** (like if the user solved it) to your server.

Answer (score 0):

Google for `JavaScript interpreter`, there are quite a few.